# How to send user login credentials after user registers

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel's default login and registration. I have successfully set up authentication, however I would like to send user's username and password to the emails they used during registration. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate a mail to user after you validated input received and before your create functions of your register controller present in

```
$email = new UserRegisterData(new User(['password' => $user->password, 'name' => $user->name]));
```

To do this you need to rewrite

```
protected function validator(array $data)
```

function in your register controller and modify that with this mail. as

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $email = new UserRegisterData(new User(['password' => $user->password, 'name' => $user->name]));

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:customers',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

once you hashed your password in create function, i think it can't be read. Also check if any security issue it may generate. Also you need to create mail as 'UserRegisterData' and add necessary code in it.